# $X$,$Y$ are $U(0,1)$ i.i.d R.V, $Z=\frac XY$, find $f_{XZ}(x,z)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

$X$,$Y$ are $U(0,1)$ i.i.d R.V, $Z=\frac XY$, find $f_{XZ}(x,z)$

This is the question, I tried in this way- 
$$Pr\{X=x \cap Z=z\}=Pr\{Y=\frac xz\}$$
$$f_{XZ}(x,z)dxdz=f_Y(\frac xz)dy$$
$$f_Y(y) = 1 = f_X(x)$$
Now, I get that $f_{XZ}(x,z)=1$ (or not?)

But, $Z \in (0,\infty)$. This is contradictory. Does that mean $f_{XZ}(x,z)=0?$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

When you have continous variables, you should not write $Pr(X=x)$, because that's zero. Anyway, even for discrete variables the first equation is wrong, it does not make sense. For example $Pr(Y=3) = Pr(Y=6/2) \ne Pr(X=6 \cap Z=2)$ (because the event $Y=3$ can happen also when $X=15$ $Z=5$, etc).

The "correct" equation would be $Pr\{X=x \cap Z=z\}=Pr\{X=x \cap Y=\frac xz\}$ and then $f_{X,Z}(x,z)=f_{X,Y}(x,\frac xz)$. But this is still wrong. 
To make it more rigourous we can speak of cumulative distributions

$$F_{X,Z}(x,z)=P(X\le x \cap Z \le z)=P(X\le x \cap \frac XY \le z)$$

Then you should find that probability by computing the area of the corresponding region inside the unit square.